# Styling not working on browser preview after applying tailwindcss class

Tags: html, css, web, tailwind-css

I applied every steps as I saw on a video on YouTube during installation of tailwindcss but whenever I want to preview my work the stylings doesn't take effect but my css file is properly linked

I have tried watching videos on how to fix it I haven't gotten any useful info yet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide the code you tried to use.